# Binding Color in Xamarin listView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

I've checked some answers before but nothing helped me. I'm trying to change background color of ViewCell in ListView by binding StackLayout BackgroundColor.
For now it looks like this[image]

Every cell should be filled with different color but it does not change at all. Code behind it:

OrderDatapage.XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
.
.
.
.
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
       <ListView x:Name="timetableList"
                        RowHeight="25"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                        Margin="0,0,0,10"
                        >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        BackgroundColor="{Binding Paint, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}"
                                                FontSize="Medium"
                                                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                                TextColor="White"
                                                BackgroundColor="Black"
                                                />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                                FontSize="Default"
                                                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                                TextColor="Black"
                                                />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Date}"
                                                FontSize="Default"
                                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                Margin="0,0,40,0"
                                                TextColor="Black"
                                                />
                             </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Converter.cs

```
class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Color.FromHex(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

OrderDataPage.cs

```
    List<TimetableItem> timeTableList { get; set; }
    public OrderDataPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timeTableList = new List<TimetableItem>();
        var timetable1 = new TimetableItem() { Number = "1", Title = "Test1", Date = "20-12-2020", Paint = "#63FF20" };
        var timetable2 = new TimetableItem() { Number = "2", Title = "Test2", Date = "20-12-2020", Paint = "#FFD933" };
        var timetable3 = new TimetableItem() { Number = "3", Title = "Test3", Date = "20-12-2020", Paint = "#C0C0C0" };
        timeTableList.Add(timetable1);
        timeTableList.Add(timetable2);
        timeTableList.Add(timetable3);

        timetableList.ItemsSource = timeTableList;

    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, did you checked with breakpoints either Value convert is getting called ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try to set Label's BackGroundColor to "Transparent" to see the StackLayout Background Color, but I am not sure if it works. Otherwise you can set Label's BackGroundColor to a particular color.

In your IValueConverter you should check if "value" is not null

```
if(value != null && value is string && (string)value != "")
    return Color.FromHex(value.ToString());
else
    return Color.Red;
```

UPDATE

I have done a little test setting the StackLayout's BackgroudColor

```
slView.SetBinding(StackLayout.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackgroundColor");
```

Where BackgroundColor is a string

```
List.Add(new Model { Description = "D1", Cost = 10.0, Qty = 1, BackgroundColor = "#9ac16e"});
List.Add(new Model { Description = "D2", Cost = 20.0, Qty = 2, BackgroundColor = "#8d0000" });
List.Add(new Model { Description = "D3", Cost = 30.0, Qty = 3, BackgroundColor = "#3a6cf6"});
```

And it works also without IValueConverter

[image: iOS]

[image: Android]

The only problem is that you loose then Highlight when you select the row

You can find a repo [HERE](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestBindingWithListView)

Comment: Setting Label's BackGroundColor to "Transparent" was a good idea for me. Thank you!